# How to enable/disable an html button based on scenarios?

Tags: html, css, button

I have a button in my webpage with below code -

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="checkout-button" id="checkout-button" name="checkout-button"></button>
```

CSS:

```
.checkout-button{
  width: 130px;
  height: 35px;
  background: url('../poc2/images/checkout.png') no-repeat;
  border: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left:35px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Now, the button works fine as I can click on it and have my corresponding php code run; the pointer turns into the hand symbol letting the user clearly know that it is clickable and that its a button.

What I would like to do is to modify the behavior of this button based on some conditions. Example pseudocode:

```
if flag=1: 
    /* enable the button, and let the user click it and run the php code */
else: 
    /* display this button, but don't let any actions take place if the user clicks on it; */
```

How do I code this enable-disable logic for the button? Basically, I want the button to work as a button under normal situations; and just as a picture without any hyperlink under certain other situations.

Comment: are you willing to use some JavaScript/JQuery?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can either do this without JavaScript (requires a page refresh) or with JavaScript and have no refresh.

Simply use the disabled attribute:

```
<button type="submit" class="checkout-button" id="checkout-button" name="checkout-button" disabled="disabled"></button>
```

And create a css style for it, if necessary. The example below shows a JavaScript solution. If the variable `disableButton` is set to `true`, the button will be disabled, else it can be clicked:

```js
const disableButton = true; //change this value to false and the button will be clickable
const button = document.getElementById('checkout-button');

if (disableButton) button.disabled = "disabled";
```

```css
.checkout-button {
  width: 130px;
  height: 35px;
  background: #333;
  border: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}

.checkout-button:disabled {
  background: #999;
  color: #555;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="checkout-button" id="checkout-button" name="checkout-button">submit</button>
```

Comment: thx for --->>> var button = document.getElementById('checkout-button');
button.disabled = 'disabled';

Answer (score 19):

You can do it either by modifying the attribute or by adding/removing a class.

### Modifying attribute

You will want to switch between `<button disabled="true">` and `<button disabled="false">`

With javascript, it could look like this:

```
if flag=1: 
    document.getElementById("your-btn").disabled = true;
else: 
    document.getElementById("your-btn").disabled = false;
```

And with jquery, like this:

```
if flag=1: 
    $('#your-btn').prop('disabled', true);
else: 
    $('#your-btn').prop('disabled', false);
```

### Adding/removing class

Add the following css:

```
.btn-disabled{
    cursor: not-allowed;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

And add/remove a class to the button.

With jquery:

```
if flag=1: 
    $('#your-btn').addClass('btn-disabled');
else: 
    $('#your-btn').removeClass('btn-disabled');
```

If you don't want jquery, but pure javascript, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript) is how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If your circumstance allows you could just remove the content in the `action` attribute from the `form` tag. Therefor when a user clicks submit, no action is taken.